# Link Live555 library - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, live555

Currently I am working on a research project to find the best library to process RTSP streams. I'm struggling with finding how to link the Live555 library.. I have built the library using the .mak files but non of my includes work on the Qt KDE.. If anyone has experience in integrating the library please point me in the right direction.
This is my .pro file:

.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    rtsp.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

LIVE555_LIBRARY_PATH = C:/live555/live

INCLUDEPATH +=
C:/live555/live/BasicUsageEnvironment/include
C:/live555/live/groupsock/include
C:/live555/live/liveMedia/include
C:/live555/live/UsageEnvironment/include

LIBS +=
C:/live555/live/BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.lib
C:/live555/live/groupsock/libgroupsock.lib
C:/live555/live/liveMedia/libliveMedia.lib
C:/live555/live/UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.lib

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    rtsp.h
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Live555QML\rtsp.h:3: error: C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'liveMedia/include/AC3AudioRTPSink.hh': No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: None of the header files link to the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path segment `liveMedia/include` seems to be duplicated in `rtsp.h` and `INCLUDEPATH`. The compiler is looking in these paths:

```
C:/live555/live/BasicUsageEnvironment/include/liveMedia/include/AC3AudioRTPSink.hh
C:/live555/live/groupsock/include/liveMedia/include/AC3AudioRTPSink.hh
C:/live555/live/liveMedia/include/liveMedia/include/AC3AudioRTPSink.hh
C:/live555/live/UsageEnvironment/include/liveMedia/include/AC3AudioRTPSink.hh
```

Try to add the folder `C:/live555/live` to `INCLUDEPATH`. If it’s OK and you use full paths everywhere, you should remove current `INCLUDEPATH` contents.

Comment: Thankyou, this solved the issue for the linking. I know this is now another issue but I am getting a linking error within the include file: 
C:\live555\live\liveMedia\include\FramedSource.hh:25: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NetCommon.h': No such file or directory

Comment: A general answer: You should locate that file on your system and add the folder to `INCLUDEPATH`. BTW this is compiling, not linking.

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant compiling.. I added the folder to the INCLUDEPATH but I still received the same error

Comment: @user3668531 Sorry, I need more details to find where’s the problem. Double check your `<any INCLUDEPATH item><path reported by compiler>` matches the real path. My previous advice to remove previous `INCLUDEPATH` contents is not applicable if the library itself uses just filenames without any path segment.

Comment: The single include now works, but then the include is not finding the dependencies within the actual library, its not finding netcommon.h within the file

Comment: @user3668531 These are not the details which I need to know, this is obvious from the error message. I’d rather like to see the current value of `INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: I have solved the problem by moving all of the .h files into one directory instead of separate ones. This has not solved the issue completely though as I believe that the .lib files are now pointing to the wrong locations.

Answer (score 0):

INCLUDEPATH += C:\live555\live\liveMedia\include \
    C:\live555\live\groupsock\include \
    C:\live555\live\UsageEnvironment\include \
    C:\live555\live\BasicUsageEnvironment\include